# Details on jQuery selectors path

Tags: jquery

I have a table with cells which share the same `id="spot"`. I would like to change all these cells.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="spot">1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="spot">3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
// 1 2
// 3 4
```

Please tell me the difference between `$("td#spot")` and `$("#spot")` as the following lines of code don't produce the same result.

```
$("#spot").each(function (item) {
    $(this).text("0");
})
// 0 2
// 3 4

$("td#spot").each(function (item) {
    $(this).text("0");
})
// 0 2
// 0 4
```

Comment: *same id is tautology*

Comment: You can't use the same id. But you can you the same classes. If you will use classes there is no difference between .spot and td.spot.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have duplicate ids. So, change `id` to class.

And then do:

```
$('.spot') //to select element anywhere in document.
```

or

```
$('td.spot'); //to select a td with "spot" class.
```

or

```
$('tr > .spot'); //to select a immediate child of tr having class "spot"
```

or

```
$('table .spot'); //to select a child at any depth  having class "spot"
```

In the first, you are just being liberal, while in the second you are being more specific.

Also, `$(this).("0")` doesn't make sense. I think you wanted `$(this).text("0")`